# Javascript tic tac toe, trying to declare a winner

Tags: javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var winArray = new Array;
var turn = 0;
var data1 = document.getElementById('data1');
var data2 = document.getElementById('data2');
var data3 = document.getElementById('data3');
var data4 = document.getElementById('data4');
var data5 = document.getElementById('data5');
var data6 = document.getElementById('data6');
var data7 = document.getElementById('data7');
var data8 = document.getElementById('data8');
var data9 = document.getElementById('data9');
var tiger = document.getElementById('tiger');
var dragon = document.getElementById('dragon');

function allowDrop(ev) {
ev.preventDefault();}
function drag(ev) {
ev.dataTransfer.setData("Text",ev.target.id);}
function drop(ev) {
ev.preventDefault();
var data=ev.dataTransfer.getData("Text");
ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data).cloneNode(true));
document.getElementById(data).setAttribute("draggable", "false");
if (data == "dragon"){
    document.getElementById("dragon").setAttribute("style", "background: yellow;");}
else{
    document.getElementById("tiger").setAttribute("style", "background: blue;");}
ev.target.removeAttribute('ondrop');
document.getElementById(data).removeAttribute('id');
turn++;
whosTurn();
checkWinner();}

function whosTurn(){

if(turn % 2 == 0){
document.getElementById("tiger").setAttribute("draggable", "false");
document.getElementById("dragon").setAttribute("draggable", "true");}
else{
document.getElementById("tiger").setAttribute("draggable", "true");
document.getElementById("dragon").setAttribute("draggable", "false");
}}

function checkWinner(){
if ((data1 == data2 && data1 == data3 && data1 == tiger) ||
(data4 == data5 && data4 == data6 && data4 == tiger) ||
(data7 == data8 && data7 == data9 && data7 == tiger) ||
(data1 == data4 && data1 == data7 && data1 == tiger) ||
(data2 == data5 && data2 == data8 && data2 == tiger) || 
(data3 == data6 && data3 == data9 && data3 == tiger) ||
(data1 == data5 && data1 == data9 && data1 == tiger) ||
(data3 == data5 && data3 == data7 && data3 == tiger)) 
{
alert("Tiger wins!");
}
else if ((data1 == data2 && data1 == data3 && data1 == dragon) ||
(data4 == data5 && data4 == data6 && data4 == dragon) ||
(data7 == data8 && data7 == data9 && data7 == dragon) ||                                                                                            
(data1 == data4 && data1 == data7 && data1 == dragon) ||
(data2 == data5 && data2 == data8 && data2 == dragon) || 
(data3 == data6 && data3 == data9 && data3 == dragon) ||
(data1 == data5 && data1 == data9 && data1 == dragon) ||
(data3 == data5 && data3 == data7 && data3 == dragon)) 
{
alert("Dragon wins!");
}}

</script>

<title>JavaScript  Drag &amp; Drop Tic-Tac-Toe</title>
</head>
<body>
<p>Drag the X and O images into the tic-tac-toe board:</p>

<table>
    <tr>
        <td id="data1" class="tictac" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"> </td>
        <td id="data2" class="tictac" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"> </td>
        <td id="data3" class="tictac" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"> </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td id="data4" class="tictac" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"> </td>
        <td id="data5" class="tictac" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"> </td>
        <td id="data6" class="tictac" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"> </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td id="data7" class="tictac" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"> </td>
        <td id="data8" class="tictac" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"> </td>
        <td id="data9" class="tictac" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"> </td>
    </tr>


</table>

<img id="dragon" src="Dragon.gif" alt="dragon" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" width="75" height="75" />
<img id="tiger" src="Tiger.gif" alt="tiger" draggable="false" ondragstart="drag(event)" width="75" height="75" />
```

I am trying to declare a winner when there is three of the same images in a row or column. But the issue is with checkWinner() that every time i drop an image into the table it automatically says that tiger is the winner
Help?

Comment: Hi, any chance you can add a link to JS Fiddle?

Comment: You should maybe be comparing the contents instead of the elements.

Comment: I can't get this to work on my machine so I can't try to modify any code but it appears that you may be trying to compare a cell (dataX) with an image (dragon or tiger). A Fiddle would help a lot...

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/rfu8zcn2/  is this right?? cant get the images to show on jsfiddle though

Comment: The drag and drop is not working for me.  Look at your comparisons and make sure you are checking the content of the cells and not just the cell itself as @Derek S and I mentioned. Beyond that it is hard to say without a working version.